# PhpMongo - how to apply AND condition for a single document present in an array?

Tags: php, mongodb

My Mongo collection has two documents

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("567168393d5c6cd46a00002a"),
   "type":"SURVEY",
   "description":"YOU HAVE AN UNANSWERED SURVEY.",
   "user_to_notification_seen_status":[  
      {  
         "user_id":1,
         "status":"UNSEEN",
         "time_updated":1450272825
      },
      {  
         "user_id":2,
         "status":"SEEN",
         "time_updated":1450273798
      },
      {  
         "user_id":3,
         "status":"UNSEEN",
         "time_updated":1450272825
      }
   ],
   "feed_id":1,
   "time_created":1450272825,
   "time_updated":1450273798
}
```

Here is the query I used to fetch only if the user_id is 2 & status is "UNSEEN".

```
**$query = array('$and' => array(array('user_to_notification_seen_status.user_id'=> 2,'user_to_notification_seen_status.status' => "UNSEEN")));**           

$cursor = $notification_collection->find($query);
```

Ideally the above query shouldn't retrieve results but it returning results. If I give an invalid id or invalid status, it is not returning any record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the query works. It matches your document because user_to_notification_seen_status contains elements with user_id: 2 and status: UNSEEN.

What you can do to get the desired results is use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/applications/aggregation/); unwind the array and then match both conditions. That way you'll only get the unwinded documents with the array element satisfying both conditions.

Run this in mongo shell (or convert to PHP equivalent). Also, change YourCollection to your actual collection name:

```
db.YourCollection.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$user_to_notification_seen_status" }, { $match: { "user_to_notification_seen_status.status": "UNSEEN", "user_to_notification_seen_status.user_id": 2 } } ] );
```

This will return no records, but if you change the id to 3 for example, it will return one.

Comment: Thanks. I formed a query like below & it returns proper records.                     `$query = array('user_to_notification_seen_status' => array('$elemMatch' => array('user_id'=> 2,'status' => "UNSEEN")));`

I used above query for an update in my collection. Here it is,
`$notification_document = $notification_collection->update($query, $new_data, $multiple_update);`                                                                  is this approach fine?

Comment: Yes, using $elemMatch is definitely one way to go. In fact, it makes more sense in your case, since you plan to update as well.

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:
$query = array(
    array('$unwind' => '$user_to_notification_seen_status'),
    array(
        '$match' => array('user_to_notification_seen_status.status' => 'UNSEEN', 'user_to_notification_seen_status.user_id' => 2),
    ),
    );
$cursor = $notification_collection->aggregate($query);
```